# add parent name prefix to dataframe structtype fields

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

we are generating a dataframe as follows

```
val res_df = df.select($"id",$"type",$"key",from_json($"value",schema).as("s")).select("id","type","key","s.*")
```

But we need to rename all the columns generated by "s.*" to have prefix "s_" before the field name.

Comment: Hi @AbhishekKumar, it seems that you have now asked the same or very very similar question for the fourth time (others questions are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63573035/rename-spark-dataframe-structtype-fields, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63514541/rename-a-columns-child-names-scol-name-in-spark-scala and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63513495/add-parent-column-name-as-prefix-to-avoid-ambiguity). Please respond to the feedback given in the other questions or edit your existing question.

Answer (score 1):

> Here is one solution to your problem:

```
import common.sparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object renameNestedColumn extends App with sparkSession{

  val schema = new StructType()
    .add(StructField("id",StringType))
    .add(StructField("value",new StructType()
        .add("city",StringType)
        .add("age",StringType)
        )
    )

  val data = Seq(Row("1",Row("montreal","30")),Row("2",Row("ny","25")))
  val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
  val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)
  df.printSchema()
  val nestedCols = df.select("value.*").columns.map(c => col(s"value.$c").as(s"prefix_$c")).toSeq++ Seq(col("id"))
  df.select(nestedCols:_*).show(false)
```

> Nested Schema

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- age: string (nullable = true)
```

> Flattened output with prefix nested columns

```
+-----------+----------+---+
|prefix_city|prefix_age|id |
+-----------+----------+---+
|montreal   |30        |1  |
|ny         |25        |2  |
+-----------+----------+---+
```